# Excel Macro - Copy Row > Insert Copied Rows Under Original Copied Row > Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I need a macro which will copy each unique row within a spreadsheet and insert copied rows in the two rows directly beneath the original copied row and then repeat for each row there after.

It would be great if the macro could also input the following text strings - "(A)" in the original copied row, "(B)" in the second and "(C)" in the third.

The text string part isnt hugely important as I can always just use a concatenate formula if required.

Screenshot of what Im trying to achieve:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have tried using an Index combined with an MROUND formula but that doesnt seem to be working. Im literally out of ideas and it cant be a manual process as there are thousands of rows.

Comment: Solved: C2: ="(A) "&INDEX(A:A,MROUND((ROW()+3)/3,1))
C3: ="(B) "&INDEX(A:A,MROUND((ROW()+3)/3,1))
C4: ="(C) "&INDEX(A:A,MROUND((ROW()+3)/3,1))

Comment: That works too - Your question stated that you needed a macro so I did not propose a formula.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the data is in column A and you want the result in column C (as per your picture), this should work:

```
Public Sub doIt()

    Dim data As Variant
    Dim modifiedData As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    data = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1)
    ReDim modifiedData(1 To (UBound(data, 1) - 1) * 3 + 1, 1 To 1) As Variant

    modifiedData(1, 1) = data(1, 1) 'header

    j = 2
    For i = 2 To UBound(data, 1)
        modifiedData(j, 1) = "(A) - " & data(i, 1)
        modifiedData(j + 1, 1) = "(B) - " & data(i, 1)
        modifiedData(j + 2, 1) = "(C) - " & data(i, 1)
        j = j + 3
    Next i

    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 3).Resize(UBound(modifiedData, 1), 1) = modifiedData
    End With

End Sub
```